# Plotting a 2D array with matplotlib.imshow

Tags: python, matplotlib, 2d

The `np.array` that results from this loop has 4383 rows and 6 columns. I have tried without success to use `pylab.imshow()` from matplotlib(pylab) to display the array. The objective is to creat an image of the array, in wich the colors gradient represent the magnitude of the array values. Each row of the array represents the variation in depth of a lake temperature in each day (4383 days). Thus the objective is to find diferences in lake temperatures in depth and with time. Thank you

```
TempLake=np.zeros((N+1,Nlayers)) 
TempLake[0]=T0 

Q=np.zeros(N+1) 
Q[0]=0.0 
for i in xrange(N): 
    Q[i+1]=Qn(HSR[i],TD[i],FW[i],TempLake[i][0]) 
    TempLake[i+1]=main_loop(Z,z,Areat0,Areat1,TempLake[i],wind[i],Q[i],Q[i+1]) 


im = plt.imshow(tem, cmap='hot') 
plt.colorbar(im, orientation='horizontal')  
plt.show()
```

This is the result: The legend is fine, but the x-axis are inverted and the image doesn´t appear
[image]

This is what I need:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `pcolor` or `pcolormesh` instead of `imshow`. This is because in `imshow` the aspect of figure is same as the array, which in your case is 4383x6.

```
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np


Z=np.array((range(1,30),range(31,60),range(61,90))).transpose()

X,Y=np.meshgrid(range(Z.shape[0]+1),range(Z.shape[1]+1))
im = plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,Z.transpose(), cmap='hot')
plt.colorbar(im, orientation='horizontal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You **can** use `imshow` if you just set the aspect when you call it. As follows:

```
im = plt.imshow(tem, cmap='hot', aspect=aspect_ratio*(cols/rows))
```

where `aspect_ratio` here would set the actual aspect ratio you want and `cols/rows` just normalizes the original aspect ratio to 1. `cols` and `rows` are the numbers of columns and rows (e.g. `rows = data.shape[0]`, `cols =  data.shape[1]`).

Comment: If you don't want to do the calculation by hand you can also use `aspect="auto"` which does the job for you, trying to fit the image to the figure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the axis function from matplotlib.pyplot:

```
axis('auto')
```

So your exemple would become :

```
TempLake=np.zeros((N+1,Nlayers)) 
TempLake[0]=T0 

Q=np.zeros(N+1) 
Q[0]=0.0 
for i in xrange(N): 
    Q[i+1]=Qn(HSR[i],TD[i],FW[i],TempLake[i][0]) 
    TempLake[i+1]=main_loop(Z,z,Areat0,Areat1,TempLake[i],wind[i],Q[i],Q[i+1]) 

im = plt.imshow(tem, cmap='hot') 
plt.colorbar(im, orientation='horizontal')
plt.axis('auto')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you give me an exammple, I can´t find this function

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm wrong but for the you can still use imshow just transposing the image

```
im = plt.imshow(tem.transpose(),cmap='hot',origin='lower',aspect='auto')
```

with lower saying that the plost start from the bottom left, and auto keyword in imshow. But as I said maybe I do not understand the problem

Comment: No, in `imshow` the aspect of figure is array dependent, so `transpose` will just rotate it by 90 degree.